# Objective C Protocols and Inheritance

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, protocols

Ok, there are several questions with "Protocol" and "Inheritance" but I can't really find the answer to my question. I have a class with a protocol. For example:

```
@class SomeClass;

@protocol SomeDelegate <NSObject>

@optional
     -(void) someMethod;

@end

@interface SomeClass : NSObject
{
     id<SomeDelegate> delegate;
}

@property id<SomeDelegate> delegate;

-(void) thisDoesStuff;

@end
```

Then I have a different class whose object will be a delegate of a SomeClass object:

```
@interface DiffClass: SomeClass<SomeDelegate>

// This method will conform to the one specified on the protocol
-(void) someMethod;

@end
```

My question is, does DiffClass inherit from SomeClass? I'm considering the syntax in Objective C for inheritance:

```
@interface ClassA : SuperClassOfClassA
```

Where, in the above, ClassA inherits from SuperClassOfClassA.

Additionally, in Objective C, is it possible to inherit from one class and adopt a protocol from a different class? I guess what I'm trying to get at is if it's possible that two objects are able to communicate to each other through delegates without having to inherit from that protocol's class (I hope I'm making sense).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In practice, your code would be very strange.

First, you don't have a class with a protocol. You have a protocol named SomeDelegate. Then you have a class SomeClass, which is unrelated to the protocol. Well, it has an instance variable that supports SomeDelegate, but that has nothing to do with the protocol.

Then you create a class that is both a subclass of SomeClass, *and* supports the SomeDelegate protocol. That's unusual. I mean DiffClass both supports the protocol itself, *and* has a delegate supporting the protocol. That's a bit strange.

Nevertheless, DiffClass is a subclass of SomeClass, and you promised that it supports the protocol SomeDelegate, so that's fine.

But really: A protocol doesn't belong to a class. I don't know what made you think that, but you have to remove that from your brain immediately. A protocol is a totally different thing and totally independent from a class. It's a set of requirements that any class may or may not fulfil. It exists independent of any class. Because a protocol is a set of requirements, a class can support that protocol by claiming it does (adding ) and by adding the required methods.

Comment: This is very brief and very clear. Exactly the answer I was looking for. I got confused by associating a protocol with the concept of an interface in other languages, which is why I wondered how they are used to make delegate mechanisms in Objective-C. I understand now though. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, DiffClass does inherit from SomeClass as you have it written. But it doesn't need to inherit from SomeClass. I'll be a bit more thorough below.

A protocol is a declaration of methods (and properties) that a class adopts. It does not have to be related to a class, although it often is for the delegation pattern.

For example, you could have a header that just declares a protocol. Let's call the file NewProtocol.h

```
@protocol NewProtocol<NSObject>
@optional
- (void)newMethod;
@end
```

Then any class can adopt that protocol. With your example above, this could be DiffClass. You do not need to declare the methods from NewProtocol again in the class interface.

```
// You would need to import NewProtocol.h
// Note that this does NOT inherit from SomeClass.
@interface DiffClass : NSObject<NewProtocol>
@end
```

Then the implementation of DiffClass would need to provide the declared protocol methods.

```
@implementation DiffClass

- (void)newMethod {
  // Do stuff.
}

@end
```

Then SomeClass could have a property for the declared protocol above.

```
@interface SomeClass : NSObject

// Often you will want weak for delegates as they can cause retain cycles otherwise.
@property(nonatomic, weak) id<NewProtocol> thingThatImplementsNewProtocol;

-(void) thisDoesStuff;

@end
```

DiffClass does now NOT inherit from SomeClass but can be used to communicate with SomeClass. You could declare a second protocol that SomeClass adopts and a property on DiffClass to have two way communication.

Often the protocol are declared in the same header file as a class for simplicity because they are intended as delegates for specific objects.

Comment: Very clear answer! The fact that many tutorials declared protocols in the same header file as classes was another thing that made me a little confused. It's brilliant that an object can inherit from one class and conform to protocols that aren't necessarily associated with the parent class to communicate with other objects! I also really like the idea that you brought up about using protocols for two-way communication! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Answer to the question 1:** with the statement

```
@interface DiffClass: SomeClass<SomeDelegate>
```

The `DiffClass` inherits from `SomeClass` and also conforms the protocol(interface) `SomeDelegate`.

**Answer to the question 2:** In Objc you can inherit only from one parent class (multiple inheritance wont be supported) but you can conform as many as protocols (interfaces) you want.

Lets take and example of an drawing App. `Shape` is a parent class and `RectangleShape`, `LineSahpe`, `TextShape`, `CircleShape` are the children from Shape class. All four children are inheriting from their parent Shape. But you need to move the shape except LineShape. There you can have protocol (interface) as `Movable`. That you can do so.

```
@protocol Movable <NSObject>

@end


@interface Shape : NSObject

@end


@interface RectangleShape : Shape <Movable>

@end


@interface LineSahpe : Shape // cannot be moved, just for an example.

@end


@interface TextShape : Shape <Movable>

@end


@interface CircleShape : Shape <Movable>

@end
```

You can have a method for the protocol like this to move all Shaped which are conforming Movable protocol (interface).

```
- (void)move:(id <Movable>)movableShape {

}
```

You can implement a communication instead of moving shapes. Protocols are really useful during advanced programming.

Hope it will help you... please feedback me.

Comment: Very clear! Thank you! I was confused about the whole concept of a protocol. I didn't know a class and a protocol are separate entities. I think the confusion comes from the fact that I associated a protocol to be like an interface in other OOP languages and classes "extend" those interfaces and implement their methods. Now that I understand protocols I can see how useful and powerful they are.